# DailyRollingFileAppender is not creating file

Tags: java, log4j

I am using following xml config but I am unable to get log ( tried with minute , hour etc. settings). I tried to change the location but no avail. Thanks for looking into it.

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="file" value="C:\logs\log4j_out.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.myproject.packg">
        <level value="all" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <!-- <priority value="debug" /> -->
         <level value="all"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
```

Comment: How are you using that logger? Did you tried loggin something into logger from `Logger.getRootLogger()`?

Comment: I am using in my controller : static Logger logger2 = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger(); and in function->  logger2.trace("Entering application.");